# this.props.xxx is undefined while using React with typescript but working properly in ES5?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Recently I started learning react with ES5 but now trying to use Type
     script in my app. Can anyone please tell me why I am not able to print
     values using **{this.props.people}** but it is working as expected when i am
     using **{this.state.people}.** I have taken example from this site.
    Please suggest me what is missing here?

[Site](http://www.hackingwithreact.com/read/1/13/rendering-an-array-of-data-with-map-and-jsx)

```js
import * as React from 'react';

class About extends React.Component<any, any> {
    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        console.log(About);
        const people = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            people.push({
                name: i,
                country: i + i
            });
        }

        this.state = {people};
    }
    public render() {
        return (
            <div>
            {this.props.people.map((person: any, index: number) => (
                <p key={index}>Hello, {person.name} from {person.country}!</p>
            ))}
        </div>
        );
    }
}
export default About;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `this.props.people` is something that is populated when your parent component send people prop. `this.state.people` is accessible because you are setting it in your constructor.

And it has got nothing to do with `ES5` or `ES6`. BTW you are using `ES6` from the arrow functions.

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  render(
    return (
      <Child people=[1, 2, 3] />
    )
  )
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    this.state = {
      people: [5, 6, 7]
    }
  }

  render() {
    return ( 
      <div>
        {this.props.people} // Will render [1, 2, 3], coming from Parent
        {this.state.people} // Will render [5, 6, 7], coming from Constructor
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: @Nandu...yes you absolutely right and this example is very clear...but I am bit confused... suppose my "About"  class is Parent in my example and I want to pass data to child..then I will send it like this <People persons={this.state.people}/> right ?

Comment: In `About`'s render method you need to call `<People persons={this.state.people>`, yes. Then in `People` component you can access persons as `this.props.people`.

Answer (score 1):

This is because in your example the props for people is never passed down, it's simply generated in the constructor and set to the state, you would have to use this.state.people.

If you want to use props, you would have to pass down people via a parent component. Have a look at the [components-props documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)